# Importing data from TXT file with while loop

Tags: php, drupal

My problem is I don´t know how to finish while loop when all rows are imported. This is Drupal 7.

If I set this `while` condition: `while ($row = $regs->fetchAssoc())` it never get inside of the loop.

If I use this condition to break loop:

```
  $cadena = array();
  while (1) {
  $row = $regs->fetchAssoc();
  $cadena[] = $row;
  if (count($cadena)<0){
  break;}
```

I get this error: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes)`

The full code is:

```
 $operations = array();
 $items = array();
 $limit = 25;
 $i = 0;

$regs =  db_query("SELECT * FROM {table_import_apunte} WHERE field_processed = :processed", array(':processed' => 0));

    while ($row = $regs->fetchAssoc()) {
            if ($i < $limit) {
                $items[] = $row;
                $i += 1;
            } else {
                $operations[] = array('csvImporter_create_nodes', array($items, 'apunte'));
                $items = array();
                $items[] = $row;            
                $i = 1;
           }      
        }

        $batch = array(
        ...
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with `while(1) { ... }` creates a infinity loop, since attaching an element to the array 'cadena' causes the count to be higher than 0 plus the count cant be lower than 0

You can try to use a foreach instead of a while

```
foreach ($regs as $row) { ... }
```